# Problems using a DLL with WPF - AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I'm trying to use Microchip's Managed DLL with their MCP2210 Evaluation Kit.  I was having success with sing it with a Console Application - I can change what LED is lit via the Potentiometer and I can read the temperature.  However, I'm having issues using it under WPF.

I'm using the exact same code to fetch values off of the device, however I'm running across `AccessViolationException`s and now `SEHException`s.  Would using a threaded approach to continually poll the device cause memory to corrupt?  And how can I avoid doing that?

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured out the issue.  Maybe.

I tried using `lock` to make sure that only one thread's accessing the device at any one time, and that seems to have cleared up all of the issues thus far.  Still need to perform more testing, but it's working so far.